# CA Cert are only added at ca-bundle-trust.crt

Tags: ssl, curl, openssl, redhat, ca

Env:

```
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.7 (Maipo)
# openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
```

so a self-sign cert is generated using OpenSSL and the cacert.pem is put under `/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/`.

Now according to the man from `update-ca-trust`, the cmd should be run to add the cert into the trust store and the cert are to be added under `/etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/`.

After running the said cmd, I see that the cert is added only to `/etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/openssl/ca-bundle.trust.crt`. But most of the application like curl refer the OS ca trust at `/etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/openssl/ca-bundle.crt` which is link to `/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt`.

```
curl -v https://172.21.19.92/api
* About to connect() to 172.21.19.92 port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 172.21.19.92...
* Connected to 172.21.19.92 (172.21.19.92) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

I understand that passing `--cacert` option would be a way to overcome it but I want to know why `update-ca-trust` only update `ca-bundle-trust.crt` and not `ca-bundle.crt` or the java Keystore extracted one as well `/etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/java/cacerts`

Comment: I have come across this problem as well. CentOS 7.7.1908 :(

Comment: What was your solution?

Comment: To answer my own comment, I simply added the cert manually to the ca-bundle.crt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual command that import certificates to `/etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/pem/tls-ca-bundle.pem` is:

```
/usr/bin/p11-kit extract --format=pem-bundle --filter=ca-anchors --overwrite --comment --purpose server-auth $DEST/pem/tls-ca-bundle.pem
```

So the filters here are `--filter=ca-anchors` + `--purpose server-auth`. When you generate cert you have to add the purpose `extendedKeyUsage=serverAuth` explicitly:

```
openssl x509 -req -in $SRV_NAME.csr -CA $CA_NAME.crt -CAkey $CA_NAME.key -passin pass:"$PASS" -out $SRV_NAME.crt \
  -days 3650 -CAcreateserial \
  -extensions v3_ca \
  -extfile <(echo "[v3_ca]"; echo "extendedKeyUsage=serverAuth"; echo "subjectAltName=$SRV_DNS_NAMES_TEXT,email:$SRV_EMAIL")
```